# Add a field to JSON ( struct + interface ) golang

Tags: json, go

Here's the response interface :

```
type Response interface{}
```

It's satisfied by a struct like this :

```
type CheckResponse struct {
    Status    string `json:"status"`
}
```

I am getting `out []Response` as an output which is to be consumed elsewhere.

I want to add a `Version` string to this JSON, before it's being sent. I've tried using anonymous structs ( but in vain ) :

```golang
for _, d := range out {
        outd := struct {
            Resp       Response `json:",inline"`
            Version    string   `json:",inline"`
        }{
            Resp:       d,
            Version: "1.1",
        }
        data, _ := json.Marshal(outd)
        log.Infof("response : %s", data)
    }
```

The output I am getting is :

```json
response : {"Resp":{"status":"UP"},"Version":"1.1"}
```

### What I want is

```json
{"status":"UP","Version":"1.1"}
```

i.e. one single flat JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline` tag is not supported by `encoding/json` and embedding interfaces will also not produce the result you want. You'll have to declare a type for the `out` value and have that type implement the `json.Marshaler` interface, you can then customize how its fields are marshaled, for example you could marshal the two fields Resp and Version separately and then "merge the result" into a single json object.

```golang
type VersionedResponse struct {
    Resp    Response
    Version string
}

func (r VersionedResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    out1, err := json.Marshal(r.Resp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    out2, err := json.Marshal(struct{ Version string }{r.Version})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // NOTE: if Resp can hold something that after marshaling
    // produces something other than a json object, you'll have
    // to be more careful about how you gonna merge the two outputs.
    //
    // For example if Resp is nil then out1 will be []byte(`null`)
    // If Resp is a slice then out1 will be []byte(`[ ... ]`)

    out1[len(out1)-1] = ',' // replace '}' with ','
    out2 = out2[1:]         // remove leading '{'

    return append(out1, out2...), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/66jIYXGUtWJ

Comment: Looks a bit hacky, but works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assert your `d` to CheckResponse type and then define dynamic struct like this

```
outd := struct {
            Resp       string `json:"status,inline"`
            Version    string   `json:",inline"`
        }
```

This is the full code for this.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Response interface {}

type CheckResponse struct {
    Status    string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    out := []Response{
        CheckResponse{Status: "UP"},
    }
    for _, d := range out {
        res, ok := d.(CheckResponse)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        outd := struct {
            Resp       string `json:"status,inline"`
            Version    string   `json:",inline"`
        }{
            Resp:       res.Status,
            Version: "1.1",
        }
        data, _ := json.Marshal(outd)
        fmt.Printf("response : %s", data)
    }
}
```

You can run [here](https://play.golang.org/p/5UeXNxLYK5i)

Comment: Adding this answer for completeness which is using [structs](https://github.com/fatih/structs) library

Here's the playground link : https://play.golang.org/p/OIk1K5zbO6J

It's extensible and easy to use, though with the drawback that you've to include another library for this.

You can use simple `map[string]interface{}` construct for the same, as used in `structs.Map`.

**Note**
1. structs for some reason, makes the json `keys` *Title Case*. That's not an issue though. Also mentioned here : https://github.com/fatih/structs/issues/122

Comment: @ricizawu is this related to my answer?

Comment: no. actually since this question was closed so couldn't add this answer and had to add it in comments. But now I see 'kush' has already added this answer as well. so the above comment is redundant now :D

Answer (score 1):

One way that will work for sure is simply use a `map[string]interface{}`, iterate over fields in `Response` via reflect or use a library like `structs`, update your map with response fields, append your version field to map, and then marshal.
Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/OIk1K5zbO6J)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type Response interface{}

type CheckResponse struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    resp := CheckResponse{Status: "success"}
    m := structs.Map(resp)
    m["Version"] = "0.1"
    out, _ := json.Marshal(m)   
    
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

Comment: This is the one, I went up with. As it's more scalable and cleaner ( looks less hacky :p )